# How can I invert the value range of a node group's input node?

Tags: materials, node-editor, mathematics

I am making a simple edge detector group, and I want to expose a value to its input. The only problem is that the value I want to expose is mapped differently than I would like. It goes from -1 to +1. I want to create a slider that controls this value such that the slider goes from 1 to 0 (backwards) instead of -1 to +1.

Here are images:

[image: Node Stuff]

[image: Slider Invert]

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution pretty quickly! I just needed a "Map Range" node.

Here's a link to the documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/vector/map_range.html

[image: The Fix]

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer as correct.

Comment: Sure thing, can't do it for a couple days though.